# Spring Cloud Sidecar load balancing does not retry on failure

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I have the following setup:

- Spring Cloud Eureka Server (Spring Boot app with `@EnableEurekaServer`)
- Spring Cloud Sidecar (running on `:8080`)
- 2 instances of the same Spring Boot app properly registered against Eureka (`@EnableEurekaClient`) and exposing a single `GET /configurations` endpoint (running on `:8081` and `:8082`)

All of this running on Java 8 + Spring Cloud 1.1.0.M5.

Invoking the REST endpoint through Sidecar on `:8080` works fine, requests are load-balanced properly and responses are correct on the client side. If I shutdown one of the 2 app instances and invoke again the endpoint, the client receives this error:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1458328852272,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException",
  "message": "Forwarding error"
}
```

The Sidecar logs show the following:

```
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.201[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Path = null
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.201[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Transfer-Encoding = null
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.201[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Content-Encoding = null
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.201[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Content-Length header = -1
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.209[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.loadbalancer.ZoneAwareLoadBalancer  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Zone aware logic disabled or there is only one zone
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.209[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m blue-config using LB returned Server: localhost:blue-config:6ef471326fe62d8877b94e2a8be06058 for request /configurations
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.211[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RestClient sending new Request(GET: ) http://localhost:8082/configurations
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.211[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Get connection: {}->http://localhost:8082, timeout = 2000
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.211[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [{}->http://localhost:8082] total kept alive: 2, total issued: 0, total allocated: 2 out of 200
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.211[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Getting free connection [{}->http://localhost:8082][null]
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.212[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stale connection check
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:50.212[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stale connection detected
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:51.240[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ HystrixTimer-3][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No fallback for HystrixCommand. 

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.getFallback(HystrixCommand.java:284) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:311) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:306) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:100) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) [rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:958) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:978) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:100) [hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]

[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.216[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Released connection is not reusable.
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.216[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Releasing connection [{}->http://localhost:8082][null]
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.217[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.218[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.l.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Got error com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect when executed on server localhost:blue-config:6ef471326fe62d8877b94e2a8be06058
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.220[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.loadbalancer.ZoneAwareLoadBalancer  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Zone aware logic disabled or there is only one zone
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.220[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m blue-config using LB returned Server: localhost:blue-config:7ffe630c9c6f6acf456faba18058bf55 for request /configurations
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.221[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient [0;39m [2m:[0;39m RestClient sending new Request(GET: ) http://localhost:8081/configurations
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.221[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Get connection: {}->http://localhost:8081, timeout = 2000
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.221[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [{}->http://localhost:8081] total kept alive: 1, total issued: 0, total allocated: 1 out of 200
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.221[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Getting free connection [{}->http://localhost:8081][null]
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.221[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stale connection check
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.223[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Attempt 1 to execute request
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.239[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NFHttpClient          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.240[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mc.n.http4.MonitoredConnectionManager    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Released connection is reusable.
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.240[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Releasing connection [{}->http://localhost:8081][null]
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.240[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Pooling connection [{}->http://localhost:8081][null]; keep alive indefinitely
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.240[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
[2m2016-03-18 15:20:52.243[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m3388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:134) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar:1.1.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar:1.1.0.M5]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar:1.1.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:112) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: blue-config timed-out and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:806) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:790) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:99) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1521) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1411) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:314) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:306) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:100) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:958) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:978) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:100) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:601) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:581) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar:1.4.23]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:99) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

The interesting thing is that the connection refused error seems to be detected (`Stale connection detected`) and a call to the other instance is done (I do see the incoming request), but the result is still an error.  I would expect the response from the retry call to be returned to the client.

Is this a milestone bug or am I missing some configuration to make this work?

Comment: It's probably doing the retry, but overall hystrix or ribbon is timing out. The default is very short. There are some configuration keys, but I'm out on vacation. Ping me and I'll find them next week.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Setting hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000 solves this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Hystrix was the one that was timing out.  Setting `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000` seems to solve the problem.

Thanks Spencer!